# Are 5e Druids able to transform into Magical Beasts, or are they restricted to ordinary beasts?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

so I just wanted to know whether druids could transform into magical beats such as the Winter Wolf in 5e. Me and my friends recently started playing so it would be nice to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Winter Wolf is a **monstrosity**, druids can only Wild Shape into beasts

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a **beast** that you have seen before.